# R - Longest common substring

Tags: r, string, substring, longest-substring

Does anyone know of an R package that solves [the longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)? I am looking for something fast that could work on vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the ["Rlibstree" package on omegahat Github](https://github.com/omegahat/Rlibstree)

This uses http://www.icir.org/christian/libstree/.

Comment: Can you post example code of the result of comparing `'hello world'` and `'hella old'` ? Does it produces `'hell'` or `'hell old'`?

Comment: First link is broken

Answer (score 2):

The question here is not totally clear on the intended application of the solution to the longest common substring problem.  A common application that I encounter is matching between names in different datasets.  The `stringdist` package has a useful function `amatch()` which I find suitable for this task.

**In brief**, `amatch()` will take as input two vectors, the first is `x` the vector of strings that you want to find matches from (this can also just be a single string), the second is `table`, which is the vector of strings you want to make comparisons to and choose the match with the longest common substring.  `amatch()` will then return a vector whose length equals that of `x` - each element of this result will be an index in `table` that contains the best match.

**Details**: `amatch()` takes a `method` argument, which you specify to be `lcs` if you want matching on longest common substring.  There are many other options for different string matching techniques (e.g. Levenshtein distance).  There is also a mandatory `maxDist` argument.  If all strings in `table` are greater "distance" from a given string in `x`, then `amatch()` will return `NA` for that element of its output.  "distance" is defined differently depending on the string matching algorithm you choose.  For lcs, it (more or less) just means how many different (non-matched) characters there are.  See documentation for details.

**Parallelization**: another nice feature of `amatch()` is that it will automatically parallelize the operation for you, making reasonable guesses about system resources to use.  If you want more control over this, you can toggle the `nthread` argument.

**Example application**:

```
library(stringdist)

Names1 = c(
"SILVER EAGLE REFINING, INC. (SW)",
"ANTELOPE REFINING",
"ANTELOPE REFINING (DOUGLAS FACILITY)"
)

Names2 = c(
"Mobile Concrete, Inc.",
"Antelope Refining, LLC. ",
"Silver Eagle Refining Inc."
)

Match_Idx = amatch(tolower(Names1), tolower(Names2), method = 'lcs', maxDist = Inf)
Match_Idx
# [1] 3 2 2

Matches = data.frame(Names1, Names2[Match_Idx])
Matches

#                                 Names1          Names2.Match_Idx.
# 1     silver eagle refining, inc. (sw) silver eagle refining inc.
# 2                    antelope refining   antelope refining, llc. 
# 3 antelope refining (douglas facility)   antelope refining, llc. 

### Compare Matches:

Matches$Distance = stringdist(Matches$Names1, Matches$Match, method = 'lcs')
```

Also, unlike functions like `LCS` from `qualV`, this will not consider "subsequence" matches that involve ignoring intermediate characters in order to form a match (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261825/longest-common-substring-in-r-finding-non-contiguous-matches-between-the-two-str)).  For instance, see this:

```
Names1 = c(
"hello"
)

Names2 = c(
"hel123l5678o",
"hell"
)

Match_Idx = amatch(tolower(Names1), tolower(Names2), method = 'lcs', maxDist = Inf)

Matches = data.frame(Names1, Match = Names2[Match_Idx])
Matches

# 1  hello  hell
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R, but I used to implement Hirschberg's algorithm which is fast and don't consume too much space.

As I remember it is only 2 or 3 recursively called short functions.

Here is a link:
http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence

So don't hesitate to implement it in R, it worths the effort since it is a very interesting algorithm.

Comment: But Vereb, that is Longest-Common Subsequence algorithm right? Subsequence is different than Substring, right? As asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28261825/1175496

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `LCS` function of `qualV` package. It is C-implemented, therefore quite efficient.

Comment: Note: that function will find the longest common subsequence (in the mathematical sense of sequence), not substring.  Thus, e.g. it will ignore characters in the middle of the strings to find matches between them.  For more details, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261825/longest-common-substring-in-r-finding-non-contiguous-matches-between-the-two-str

Answer (score 0):

The `LCSn` function (`PTXQC` package) can find the longest common string for all strings in the input vector. A warning is that the shortest string is used as the base, so it might not give you what you want when comparing multiple strings. However, it is a good option to compare two sequences.

```r
library(PTXQC)
LCSn(c("hello","hello world"))
#[1] "hello"

LCSn(c("hello", "hel123l5678o"))
#[1] "hel"
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76291346/8806649)