# Find common substrings between two character variables

Tags: r, lcs

I have two character variables (names of objects) and I want to extract the largest common substring.

```
a <- c('blahABCfoo', 'blahDEFfoo')
b <- c('XXABC-123', 'XXDEF-123')
```

I want the following as a result:

```
[1] "ABC" "DEF"
```

These vectors as input should give the same result:

```
a <- c('textABCxx', 'textDEFxx')
b <- c('zzABCblah', 'zzDEFblah')
```

These examples are representative.  The strings contain identifying elements, and the remainder of the text in each vector element is common, but unknown.

Is there a solution, in one of the following places (in order of preference):

1. Base R
2. Recommended Packages
3. Packages available on CRAN

The answer to the supposed-duplicate does not fulfill these requirements.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429476/longest-common-substring-problem

Comment: Also this: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02a/archive/68013.html

Comment: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Biostrings/html/pmatchPattern.html, and this http://www.emoticode.net/r/longest-common-substring.html

Comment: I'm looking for a base function, or something in a recommended package (available on CRAN).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg It doesn't look that it exists, unless Google chose to hide it.

Comment: Is your objection to the BSD license attached to Rlibstree (at the link in the first question above)?  Are you OK with anything on CRAN, or just the [recommended packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Add_002don-packages-from-CRAN)?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I can't find Rlibstree.  Were you able to install it?

Comment: Ok, I found it [here](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.4/extra/html/Rlibstree.html), but I can't get the desired output with it.  I'd love to upvote an answer that can.

Comment: @GSee -- I have a slow download right now, but am interested too, and will investigate once I get the Bioconductor version installed (and all associated packages updated).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, what you've is the *longest uncommon substring*, isn't it? For your first example, LCS is `blah`.

Comment: @Arun, he's comparing `a` and `b`

Comment: The funny thing is that I looked at this and said, "hey, if those were numbers, this would be a correlation integral."  Does `libstree`'s algorithm do anything similar?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, If you weren't joking (sorry if so, for not getting the humor), then [**check this out**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring) for what libstree does :).

Comment: @Arun  Thanks for the pointer.  I was actually wondering about moving one string w.r.t. the other, and looking for  maximal overlap, but realized that wouldn't give much useful information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a CRAN package for that:

```
library(qualV)

sapply(seq_along(a), function(i)
    paste(LCS(strsplit(a[i], '')[[1]], strsplit(b[i], '')[[1]])$LCS,
          collapse = ""))
```

Comment: (+1) for CRAN package. I find the input to this function *really* weird though. I mean, it's obvious that one has to create all suffixes. Why ask the user to do it? Nice thing is they've their own implementation of LCS in C.

Comment: it has to do with how the rest of the package works - most of the processing is done on vectors

Comment: I don't mind the function taking vector inputs. But it should just be `LCS(a[i], b[i])` is what I meant. We shouldn't be generating suffixes.

Comment: @Arun, yes, I understand what you were saying and what I'm saying is that the package is centered around processing of vectors of numbers and this function is meant to be LCSequence, which is a generalization of LCSubstring. It would of course be nice if someone wrote the specialized version for strings, but oh well.

Comment: This is not working for me. 
Here is my code:
` > library(qualV)` 
` > a <- "* LEAR ROBINSO"`
` > b <- "* STAR CITY GA"`
` > c <- LCS(substring(a, seq(1, nchar(a)), seq(1, nchar(a))), substring(b,seq(1, nchar(b)), seq(1, nchar(b))))`
` > c$LCS`
` [1] "*" " " "A" "R" " " "I"`
` > c <- paste(LCS(substring(a, seq(1, nchar(a)), seq(1, nchar(a))), substring(b, seq(1, nchar(b)), seq(1, nchar(b))))$LCS,collapse="")`
` > c`
` [1] "* AR I"`

Comment: @ConfusedMan does this link describe your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28261825/1175496 ? Were you expecting an output of only `'AR '` rather than `'AR I'`?

Comment: Also, I I think it's easier to replace `substring(a[i], seq(1, nchar(a[i])), seq(1, nchar(a[i])))` with `strsplit(a[i],'')[[1]]`. At first I just thought this was easier to read. But [this site] suggests `strsplit(...)` is also **more efficient**

Comment: Finally, as long as LCS is designed to accept vectors, here is a translation of strings to vectors: `function(a,b){
    av <- strsplit(a,'')[[1]];  
    bv <- strsplit(b,'')[[1]];  
    return(paste(LCS(av,bv)$LCS, collapse=''));  
}`

Comment: @TheRedPea Understood. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry the link which says strsplit is [more efficient](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) `## strsplit is more efficient ...`

Answer (score 9):

If you dont mind using bioconductor packages, then, You can use `Rlibstree`. The installation is pretty straightforward.

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rlibstree")
```

Then, you can do:

```
require(Rlibstree)
ll <- list(a,b)
lapply(data.frame(do.call(rbind, ll), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
           function(x) getLongestCommonSubstring(x))

# $X1
# [1] "ABC"

# $X2
# [1] "DEF"
```

---

On a side note: I'm not quite sure if `Rlibstree` uses `libstree 0.42` or `libstree 0.43`. Both libraries are present in the source package. I remember running into a memory leak (and hence an error) on a huge array in **perl** that was using `libstree 0.42`. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have too many things I don't want to do, I did this instead:

```
Rgames> for(jj in 1:100) {
+ str2<-sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE)
+ str1<-sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE)
+ longs[jj]<-length(lcstring(str1,str2)[[1]])
+ }
Rgames> table(longs)
longs
 2  3  4 
59 39  2
```

Anyone care to do a statistical estimate of the actual distribution of matching strings? 
(`lcstring` is just a brute-force home-rolled function; the output contains all max strings which is why I only look at the first list element)