# Identify a common pattern

Tags: r, string, lcs

Is there a (easy) possibility to identify a common pattern which two strings share? 
Here is a little example to make clear what I mean:

I have two variables containing a string. Both include the same pattern ("ABC") and also some "noise".

```
a <- "xxxxxxxxxxxABCxxxxxxxxxxxx"
b <- "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyABC"
```

Lets say I don't know the common pattern and I want R to find out that both strings contain "ABC". How can I do this?

*edit

The first  example was maybe a bit to simplistic. Here is a example from my real data.

```
a <- "DUISBURG-HAMBORNS"
b <- "DUISBURG (-31.7.29)S"
```

Both strings contain "DUISBURG" which I want the function to identify.

*edit

I took the solution proposed in the link posted in the comments. But I still have not exactly what I want.

```
library(qualV)
LCS(strsplit(a[1], '')[[1]],strsplit(b[1], '')[[1]])$LCS

[1] "D" "U" "I" "S" "B" "U" "R" "G" "-" " " " " "S"
```

If the function is looking for the longest common subsequence of the two vectors, why does it not stop after `"D" "U" "I" "S" "B" "U" "R" "G"`? .

Comment: We need to know more about possible common patterns and this "noise". For example, does "abc" and "cda" give 2 common patterns "a" and "c"?

Comment: Ok, there is a point. I want patterns with at least 3 or 4 elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196327/find-common-substrings-between-two-character-variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function `LCS` from `qualV` package (in [Find common substrings between two character variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196327/find-common-substrings-between-two-character-variables); *not* a possible duplicate) does something else than what you need. It solves [the longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), where subsequences are not required to occupy consecutive positions within the original sequences.

What you have is [the longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), for which you could use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode) algorithm, and here is the code assuming that there is a unique (in terms of length) longest common substring:

```
a <- "WWDUISBURG-HAMBORNS"
b <- "QQQQQQDUISBURG (-31.7.29)S"

A <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
B <- strsplit(b, "")[[1]]

L <- matrix(0, length(A), length(B))
ones <- which(outer(A, B, "=="), arr.ind = TRUE)
ones <- ones[order(ones[, 1]), ]
for(i in 1:nrow(ones)) {
  v <- ones[i, , drop = FALSE]
  L[v] <- ifelse(any(v == 1), 1, L[v - 1] + 1)
}
paste0(A[(-max(L) + 1):0 + which(L == max(L), arr.ind = TRUE)[1]], collapse = "")
# [1] "DUISBURG"
```

Comment: I found this function as an almost perfect solution to a similar problem I have, though I have one issue. How to make it handle cases where there is no commong substring? Specifically, I don't care about the exact substring but its length, so far I run this one and then use nchar, but the function returns error, when two strings don't have any matches in.

Comment: I have found that in abovementioned case `ones` is empty, so an if clause after it solved it. Another issue I have is how to apply it properly to my dataset? I need to compare strings from two columns row-by-row in the entire table.

Comment: @PrzeM, you can always run a `for` loop. Also, you could define a function `fun` that takes a vector of length 2 as an argument (first element would be `a`, second `b`) and do `apply(df, 1, fun)`.

Comment: The dataset is quite large (a few hundred thousand rows), so I would prefer to avoid loops because of performance issues. I have created a separate question with my code and details of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263456/applying-a-function-of-two-columns-over-each-row-of-data-frame

Comment: @PrzeM, my comment answers your question; since you care about efficiency I suggest you mention it there as well.

Comment: I have just tried implementing `for` loop, but it returns the same error as `apply`.