# Bioconductor vs CRAN

Tags: r, repository, bioconductor, cran

Today I've discovered that there is another repository except CPAN. This repository is [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/). So far I've noticed that Bioconductor's [installation](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/) process is slightly different compared to classic CRAN's `install.packages()`. Should I worry when I want to use some packages from Bioconductor? Is it possible to get into some dependencies problems (as when you are mixing e.g. ubuntu/debian repositories etc.) etc.? I'm asking because e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197727/1616488) says:

> If you dont mind using bioconductor packages, then, You can use...

What is wrong with Bioconductor or potentially another repositories?

Comment: please clarify why I get downwote, thanks

Comment: good question but off-topic IMO. bioc or any public repo will share the same advantages and disadvantages as cran. I would judge the packages/authors themselves as there is a lot of garbage on cran as well as bioc. I think you have misinterpreted arun's comment as "bioconductor is a risky repo, use at own risk" which I do not think he was implying

Comment: In the linked question, I specifically asked for base, recommend, or CRAN-available modules for the solution.  That's why Arun included that comment.  Why I needed to restrict the source of any code is not important here.  If you can use Bioconductor packages, go for it.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg now I did and and I've end up with error `Failed with error:  ‘package ‘Rlibstree’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it’
` any ideas?

Comment: @WakanTanka https://github.com/omegahat/Rlibstree

Comment: @rawr yes I've checked it but last commit was 4 years ago so it looks like same version as in Bioconductor.

Comment: I'm saying that you can use those instructions to install it from source

Comment: @WakanTanka if you're having problems installing a Bioconductor package, ask on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Answer (score 7):

BioConductor is very well structured, tested and operating. There is nothing wrong with it.  Please just read up on it yourself.

And please do understand there *is practically no limit to the number of different repositories* you can use.  'Base R' already knows about CRAN, BioConductor and OmegaHat (though I am unsure how active it currently is, it too has a proud 15 year history).

Lastly, you [easily build / host / use your own repositories using drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html).