# function that extracts a common continuous sequence in R

Tags: r, tm

Tell me please, is there the function that extracts a common continuous sequence of characters from the symbol vector. Ie, for example, from the row vector at the input: `` c ("mom soap frame", "sweet mom", "dad, mom, me", "`mom`ent") `` get the output vector c `("mom")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find common substrings between two character variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196327/find-common-substrings-between-two-character-variables)

Comment: @konvas: imho not really a duplicate, since here you want to look for a LCS within 1 vector, and not  finding an LCS between two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v <- c ("mom soap frame", "sweet mom", "dad, mom, me", "moment")

library(PTXQC)
LCSn(v, min_LCS_length = 0)

#[1] "mom"
```